# String interpolation in Perl6

Tags: raku, string-interpolation

I have difficulty figuring out why the statement

```
say "\c500";
```

produces the character 'Ǵ' on my screen as expected, while the following statements give me an error message at compile time ("Unrecognized \c character"):

```
my $i = 500;
say "\c$i";
```

even though

```
say "$i"; # or 'say $i.Str;' for that matter
```

produces "500" (with "$i".WHAT indicating type Str).

Comment: What version of perl 6 are you using?

Comment: @jjmerelo I'm running Rakudo Star 2018.01, implementin Perl v6.c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to use `$i.chr`, which is documented [here](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/uniparse). `\c` is handled specially within strings, and does not seem to admit anything that is not a literal.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. Meanwhile, my conceptual understanding may have progressed a bit. I guess that the \c[...] construct is also a string interpolation construct, whose processing precedes that of $i, causing a conflict. Initially, I thought \c[...] was handled by the say function, but this seems not to be case, as `say '\c500'` simply yields `\c500`.

Comment: `\c500` is an escape sequence, a bit like `\n`. In a double-quoted string, since method calls interpolate, `$i.chr()` will interpolate also.

Answer (score 5):

The string literal parser in Perl 6 is a type of domain specific language.

Basically what you write gets compiled similarly to the rest of the language.

```perl6
"abc$_"
```

```perl6
&infix:«~»('abc',$_.Str)
```

In the case of `\c500`, you could view it as a compile-time constant.

```perl6
"\c500"
```

```perl6
(BEGIN 500.chr)
```

Actually it is more like:

```perl6
(BEGIN 500.HOW.find_method_qualified(Int,500,'chr').(500))
```

Except that the compiler for string literals actually tries to compile it to an abstract syntax tree, but is unable to because there hasn't been code added to handle this case of `\c`.
Even if there was, `\c` is effectively compiled to run at `BEGIN` time, which is before `$_` has a value.

---

Also `\c` is used for more than `.chr`

```perl6
"\c9" eq "\c[TAB]" eq "\cI" eq "\t"
```

(Note that `\cI` represents the character you would get by typing <kbd>Cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> on a posix platform)

So which of these should `\c$_` compile to?

```perl6
$_.chr
$_.parse-names
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.index($_).succ.chr
```

---

If you want `.chr` you can write it as one of the following. (spaces added where they are allowed)

```perl6
"abc$_.chr( )def"
"abc{ $_.chr }def"
"abc{ .chr }def"
'abc' ~ $_.chr ~ 'def'
```

Comment: This is instructive. Thank you. - In digesting your answer, I read that .parse-names has been deprecated in favor of .uniparse; just for those who may read this some time down the road.